# Partner WSDL Stub Type Info

Tags: apex, soap-api, wsdl2apex

Can someone explain whats the meaning 1, 1 in the following type info? and also false meaning not required type?

private String[] type_x_type_info = new String[]{'type','urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','false'};

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find these details in the source code of [Wsdl2Apex](https://github.com/forcedotcom/WSDL2Apex). In particular, you want to look of references to [TYPE_INFO_PREFIX](https://github.com/forcedotcom/WSDL2Apex/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=TYPE_INFO_PREFIX).

Generally it will be:

- XML Element Name
- Namespace for base type
- XML Type
- minOccurs
- maxOccurs
- isNillable

Have a look at [What are the parameters for the Salesforce WebServiceCallout.invoke method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4392616/54026)